# ¿Cómo hago para poner un formulario encima de una imágen?

Tags: formularios, imagen

Recién estoy empezando a crear mi primera pagina web y me he encontrado con este problema que no puedo colocar un formulario encima de una imagen. He buscado un montón por internet y no he podido. Todas las soluciones que he visto es con la imagen como fondo de la página web (background), pero la mía no es así. Analicé mi código y no encuentro el error. También me gustaría saber cómo puedo hacer para que la sección de género quede organizada, ya que género está a lado de masculino y no sé cómo hacer para que quede abajo. Este es el código:

```css
.body {
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    font-size: 70pt;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
/* Navigation */
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='192' height='192' viewBox='0 0 192 192'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23080c47' fill-opacity='0.75' d='M192 15v2a11 11 0 0 0-11 11c0 1.94 1.16 4.75 2.53 6.11l2.36 2.36a6.93 6.93 0 0 1 1.22 7.56l-.43.84a8.08 8.08 0 0 1-6.66 4.13H145v35.02a6.1 6.1 0 0 0 3.03 4.87l.84.43c1.58.79 4 .4 5.24-.85l2.36-2.36a12.04 12.04 0 0 1 7.51-3.11 13 13 0 1 1 .02 26 12 12 0 0 1-7.53-3.11l-2.36-2.36a4.93 4.93 0 0 0-5.24-.85l-.84.43a6.1 6.1 0 0 0-3.03 4.87V143h35.02a8.08 8.08 0 0 1 6.66 4.13l.43.84a6.91 6.91 0 0 1-1.22 7.56l-2.36 2.36A10.06 10.06 0 0 0 181 164a11 11 0 0 0 11 11v2a13 13 0 0 1-13-13 12 12 0 0 1 3.11-7.53l2.36-2.36a4.93 4.93 0 0 0 .85-5.24l-.43-.84a6.1 6.1 0 0 0-4.87-3.03H145v35.02a8.08 8.08 0 0 1-4.13 6.66l-.84.43a6.91 6.91 0 0 1-7.56-1.22l-2.36-2.36A10.06 10.06 0 0 0 124 181a11 11 0 0 0-11 11h-2a13 13 0 0 1 13-13c2.47 0 5.79 1.37 7.53 3.11l2.36 2.36a4.94 4.94 0 0 0 5.24.85l.84-.43a6.1 6.1 0 0 0 3.03-4.87V145h-35.02a8.08 8.08 0 0 1-6.66-4.13l-.43-.84a6.91 6.91 0 0 1 1.22-7.56l2.36-2.36A10.06 10.06 0 0 0 107 124a11 11 0 0 0-22 0c0 1.94 1.16 4.75 2.53 6.11l2.36 2.36a6.93 6.93 0 0 1 1.22 7.56l-.43.84a8.08 8.08 0 0 1-6.66 4.13H49v35.02a6.1 6.1 0 0 0 3.03 4.87l.84.43c1.58.79 4 .4 5.24-.85l2.36-2.36a12.04 12.04 0 0 1 7.51-3.11A13 13 0 0 1 81 192h-2a11 11 0 0 0-11-11c-1.94 0-4.75 1.16-6.11 2.53l-2.36 2.36a6.93 6.93 0 0 1-7.56 1.22l-.84-.43a8.08 8.08 0 0 1-4.13-6.66V145H11.98a6.1 6.1 0 0 0-4.87 3.03l-.43.84c-.79 1.58-.4 4 .85 5.24l2.36 2.36a12.04 12.04 0 0 1 3.11 7.51A13 13 0 0 1 0 177v-2a11 11 0 0 0 11-11c0-1.94-1.16-4.75-2.53-6.11l-2.36-2.36a6.93 6.93 0 0 1-1.22-7.56l.43-.84a8.08 8.08 0 0 1 6.66-4.13H47v-35.02a6.1 6.1 0 0 0-3.03-4.87l-.84-.43c-1.59-.8-4-.4-5.24.85l-2.36 2.36A12 12 0 0 1 28 109a13 13 0 1 1 0-26c2.47 0 5.79 1.37 7.53 3.11l2.36 2.36a4.94 4.94 0 0 0 5.24.85l.84-.43A6.1 6.1 0 0 0 47 84.02V49H11.98a8.08 8.08 0 0 1-6.66-4.13l-.43-.84a6.91 6.91 0 0 1 1.22-7.56l2.36-2.36A10.06 10.06 0 0 0 11 28 11 11 0 0 0 0 17v-2a13 13 0 0 1 13 13c0 2.47-1.37 5.79-3.11 7.53l-2.36 2.36a4.94 4.94 0 0 0-.85 5.24l.43.84A6.1 6.1 0 0 0 11.98 47H47V11.98a8.08 8.08 0 0 1 4.13-6.66l.84-.43a6.91 6.91 0 0 1 7.56 1.22l2.36 2.36A10.06 10.06 0 0 0 68 11 11 11 0 0 0 79 0h2a13 13 0 0 1-13 13 12 12 0 0 1-7.53-3.11l-2.36-2.36a4.93 4.93 0 0 0-5.24-.85l-.84.43A6.1 6.1 0 0 0 49 11.98V47h35.02a8.08 8.08 0 0 1 6.66 4.13l.43.84a6.91 6.91 0 0 1-1.22 7.56l-2.36 2.36A10.06 10.06 0 0 0 85 68a11 11 0 0 0 22 0c0-1.94-1.16-4.75-2.53-6.11l-2.36-2.36a6.93 6.93 0 0 1-1.22-7.56l.43-.84a8.08 8.08 0 0 1 6.66-4.13H143V11.98a6.1 6.1 0 0 0-3.03-4.87l-.84-.43c-1.59-.8-4-.4-5.24.85l-2.36 2.36A12 12 0 0 1 124 13a13 13 0 0 1-13-13h2a11 11 0 0 0 11 11c1.94 0 4.75-1.16 6.11-2.53l2.36-2.36a6.93 6.93 0 0 1 7.56-1.22l.84.43a8.08 8.08 0 0 1 4.13 6.66V47h35.02a6.1 6.1 0 0 0 4.87-3.03l.43-.84c.8-1.59.4-4-.85-5.24l-2.36-2.36A12 12 0 0 1 179 28a13 13 0 0 1 13-13zM84.02 143a6.1 6.1 0 0 0 4.87-3.03l.43-.84c.8-1.59.4-4-.85-5.24l-2.36-2.36A12 12 0 0 1 83 124a13 13 0 1 1 26 0c0 2.47-1.37 5.79-3.11 7.53l-2.36 2.36a4.94 4.94 0 0 0-.85 5.24l.43.84a6.1 6.1 0 0 0 4.87 3.03H143v-35.02a8.08 8.08 0 0 1 4.13-6.66l.84-.43a6.91 6.91 0 0 1 7.56 1.22l2.36 2.36A10.06 10.06 0 0 0 164 107a11 11 0 0 0 0-22c-1.94 0-4.75 1.16-6.11 2.53l-2.36 2.36a6.93 6.93 0 0 1-7.56 1.22l-.84-.43a8.08 8.08 0 0 1-4.13-6.66V49h-35.02a6.1 6.1 0 0 0-4.87 3.03l-.43.84c-.79 1.58-.4 4 .85 5.24l2.36 2.36a12.04 12.04 0 0 1 3.11 7.51A13 13 0 1 1 83 68a12 12 0 0 1 3.11-7.53l2.36-2.36a4.93 4.93 0 0 0 .85-5.24l-.43-.84A6.1 6.1 0 0 0 84.02 49H49v35.02a8.08 8.08 0 0 1-4.13 6.66l-.84.43a6.91 6.91 0 0 1-7.56-1.22l-2.36-2.36A10.06 10.06 0 0 0 28 85a11 11 0 0 0 0 22c1.94 0 4.75-1.16 6.11-2.53l2.36-2.36a6.93 6.93 0 0 1 7.56-1.22l.84.43a8.08 8.08 0 0 1 4.13 6.66V143h35.02z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.cuadro-de-fondo {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 60%;
}

#formulario{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="password"] {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    border: 3px solid white;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
  }

.masculino {
    background-color: darkgray;
    font-style: oblique;
    border-style: black;
}

.femenino {
    background-color: darkgray;
    font-style: oblique;
    border-style: black;
}

.otro {
    background-color: darkgray;
    font-style: oblique;
    border-style: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <img src="fondoazulmarino.png.jpg" class="cuadro-de-fondo"/>
</body>
<form id="formulario">
    <div>
        <label for="Usuario">Nombre de usuario</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="Usuario" class="usuario" method="GET" /><br />
        <label for="Correo Electrónico">Correo electrónico</label>
        <input type="email" name="Correo Electrónico" class="correo-electronico" method="GET" /><br />
        <label for="Contraseña">Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" name="Contraseña" class="contraseña" method="POST" />
        <label for="Género">Género</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Género" value="masculino" class="masculino" />Masculino<br />
        <input type="radio" name="Género" value="femenino" class="femenino" />Femenino<br />
        <input type="radio" name="Género" value="otro" class="otro" />Otro<br />
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="enviar" action="https://medicine.cheeck.com/pagina.principal" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Por el código que estas compartiendo creo que deberías incluir el formulario dentro del body. Por otro lado, puedes estilar la etiqueta Género con un display block. Prueba esto:

```html
<body>
   <div>
      <form id="formulario">
         <label for="Usuario">Nombre de usuario</label><br>
         <input type="text" name="Usuario" class="usuario" method="GET" /><br />
         <label for="Correo Electrónico">Correo electrónico</label>
         <input type="email" name="Correo Electrónico" class="correo-electronico" method="GET" /><br />
         <label for="Contraseña">Contraseña</label>
         <input type="password" name="Contraseña" class="contraseña" method="POST" />
         <label for="Género" style="display: block">Género</label>
         <input type="radio" name="Género" value="masculino" class="masculino" />Masculino<br />
         <input type="radio" name="Género" value="femenino" class="femenino" />Femenino<br />
         <input type="radio" name="Género" value="otro" class="otro" />Otro<br />
         <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="enviar" action="https://medicine.cheeck.com/pagina.principal" />
      </form>
   </div>
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/35/Tux.svg/165px-Tux.svg.png" class="cuadro-de-fondo"/>
</body>
```

Fíjate también que sería interesante que el div incluyera todo el formulario.

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda.

Comment: Hola @r4ziel gracias por tu respuesta, he probado tu código y me llevó el formulario para arriba y la imágen para abajo.